# Simulate multiple users connection to Cassandra using java

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I'm developing an application using java. The objective is to simulate multiple users connection to Cassandra (concurrent connections), all of them connected to same cluster.

My questions is: Should I implement multiple sessions where each session simulate a user. or only one session for the whole application.? Also how to implement multiple sessions if possible.?

Its appreciated if there is a reference or examples.

Comment: What do you want to measure - how multiple users create a load via same app. Or multiple users create a load as different apps?

Comment: I want to measure how multiple users create a load on Cassandra DB. whether from same app or not. the app I'm developing is only to simulate multiple users connection and perform some cql .

Answer (score 0):

You should always consider using a single session with a connection pool for concurrent requests.  you can build a retry mechanism if the session goes bad. having said that you can technically create redundant sessions, the driver would allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use only one `Cluster`/`Session` object per application, as each `Session` object creates a [pool of connections to every node of the cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/pooling/) + [a control connection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/control_connection/) to get notifications about schema & topology changes, etc., and having too many connections would add an additional load to the nodes. As described in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/pooling/), single network connection could carry on multiple requests simultaneously, and you can increase the number of the in-flight requests if you need, but it's not recommended to set them too high, as the high number of in-flight requests is a sign that nodes aren't able to execute queries so fast - this could happen if you're running queries that use `ALLOW FILTERING`, or fetching too much data.

You can find more information in the DataStax's guide "[Developing applications with DataStax drivers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/devapp/doc/devapp/aboutDrivers.html)".